# Mercury in a thermometer rising in leaps

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

While measuring temperature i noticed that mercury in a thermometer was not rising monotonically. It would rise suddenly, then would stay for a while and then rise again. Those leaps are about 0.5 mm on my medical thermometer and can be witnessed for a short time when the mercury column is rising fast.
I am completely puzzled by this behavior of the mercury.

Comment: That sounds like stick-slip motion. There was an article in Nature: https://www.nature.com/articles/34617 (payewall; abstract only).

Comment: @Pieter But doesn't the stick-slip motion explanation require the mercury to be significantly contractible? Otherwise the friction force required to keep mercury from expanding has to be enormous.

Comment: The shape of the meniscus would give flexibility.